# Turning a usual django website into a RESTful api

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

I've been working on. A web project for few months now.And it's a simple website with usual django models views urls and templates,with simple Ajax using jquery for the templates.

Now thinking of having a possibility of making an application soon. I am thinking of using Tastypie to make a RESTful api for my website. So the idea is to

1. Use Tastypie to make a RESTful api.
2. Using backbone.js to make my website a single page application
3. Using plist and json for my android and ios applications.

My concern starts here, with this new course of action, would. I have to make most of my website again? And if that is the case should I stop working on what I've already made and then start from scratch following the above guidelines? Again, in context to tastypie and backbone.js, what would happen to my already written views and template logic?

I've been reasearching over this topic alot and cannot find a definitive answer. So thought of asking all of you who are already experienced or have gone through the same transition.

I have almost no exposure to RESTful APIs. But I am getting inclined towards a RESTful approach as it would make app development easier.

PS. I would really appreciate if I don't get negative votes for it, but advice instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it out side by side **in the same site/project**. Keep the existing django views. Add new tastypie ones under a different URL, for instance "/api/".

Likewise, a single page app? That is just one new template *next to the existing ones*. Keep it at "/single/" for the moment. And keep the existing pages.

The actual functionality will probably stay the same. Extract useful code as separate functions out of your existing views and call them from both tastypie and your original views. This will probably even make your existing code clearer and cleaner :-)

Comment: That does seem like an interesting approach :) so I can still keep the website in beta while it is in the more "traditional" form, and at the same time work on an alternate URL scheme for my tastypie-bacbone.js and then migrate to that without loosing any user base.

 I do understand a little bit how tastypie works out with the usual Django. But how would I add on backbone.js with Django? would you happen to know of any good tutorials that can walk me through it?

Comment: The risk with keeping it without version handling is the risk you get by changing code. If you version handle it you will hardly never risk the two projects to infect each other, and if they do, it's easy to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's much of a philosophical question.

If the site is on a deadline or in production **I would probably put it in git and give it two head branches**:

- production branch
- refactor branch

The benefit then is that you can keep the old site up and add new features and merge this in your refactor branch.

Then again it much depends on the complexity and how the site acts today.

Doing the two branch system will give you the option to stop the refactor without losing your old version.

Comment: So from your answer I gather its going to be a BIG change in terms of the design, so would have to start back almost from scratch, is that correct? and I do understand a little bit how tastypie works out with the usual Django. But how would I add on backbone.js with Django? would you happen to know of any good tutorials that can walk me through it?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have any good guides. And also it's very hard to say anything without knowing the size of the project. My best advice is to have a complete product even if it not fully satisfying. Then you can implement new features in the complete product simultaneous with the refactor product.